# Inclusion for limit infimum and limit supremum of sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\{E_n\}$, $\{F_n\}$ are sequences of sets. Prove that $$\liminf E_n\cup \liminf F_n \subset \liminf (E_n\cup F_n)\subset \liminf E_n \cup \limsup.$$

I have not a problem with the first inclusion. Also I have not a problem with the second inclusion. But I dont understand why we can not state that $$\liminf (E_n\cup F_n)\subset \liminf E_n \cup \liminf F_n.$$

I have attached the solution for first and second inclusions for better understanding my question.

[image]

**Question**: The inclusion that I have stated is obvious or it is uncorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint, $E_n=A$ for $n$ even, $E_n=B$ for $n$ odd, $F_n=B$ for $n$ even, $F_n=A$ for $n$ odd. Then the right side of your inclusion is empty but the left side  is $A \cup B$.

Comment: Thanks! One question. It looks like I understood limsup and liminf uncorrect.  If I have a sequence of sets like $E_n=\{{A, B, A, B, A, B,...} \}$, where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint the $\limsup E_n =\{A,B\}$?

Comment: Yes, that is right. @Mokhmad-SalekhKhekhaev